# 301 redirect from mydomain.co.uk to www.mydomain.co.uk using IIS

Tags: iis-7, 301-redirect

I soon will be purchasing a virtual windows server and will be using IIS7

I’m keen for SEO purposes to 301 redirect any users from mydomain.co.uk to www.mydomain.co.uk, but as I have root access to my server I would like to use IIS7 rather than modifying my application

can anyone explain how this is done ?

thanks

Trueglly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS Manager, select (Server) -> Sites -> (Site name), click ‘Bindings’ in the Actions pane, and Edit the binding so the real site responds *only* to the host name `www.mydomain.co.uk`.

Now create a second site (Sites -> Add Web Site...) bound to `mydomain.co.uk` and any other hostnames you want to send to `www`. Select the new site and double-click the ‘HTTP Redirect’ feature. Enable ‘Redirect requests to this destination:’ and point it to `http://www.mydomain.co.uk/`. For SEO purposes, set the ‘Status code’ to 301.

Answer (score 1):

Go to IIS Manager and click on the Sites->sitename you want to redirect. If the HTTP Redirect Role Service is enabled then you should see the HTTP Redirect icon in the Home panel.

If it's not there then you need to load it. Start Server Manager and go to Roles->Web Server (IIS)->Role Services -> Add Role Services and install HTTP Redirection.

Your IIS Server Manager Sites>sitename home panels shoulds now have the HTTP redirect module available.

Comment: hello, thanks for the response, ive tried this but i keep getting this error in FF - 

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

i have entered - http://www.mydomain.dev/ (.dev is my local dev copy), and selected 301.

i have also tried www.mydomain.dev/ but that just repeats the URL until this error is set - The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value.

any ideas ?

Comment: When I did this it worked as expected. Can you access the www.mydomain.co.uk site before you start redirecting from mydomain.co.uk ? If not then get it working and then try the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/ 
its very easy with that module